Python __main__.py cannot import from its own module
I have a flask web application, but I get a module not found error when I am importing modules from my own app:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Users/joey/projects/app/app/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import serve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

If I have an app something like this:
__main__.py:
from app import serve

serve()

__init__.py:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from .routes import home_page, download_page, upload_page, favicon_page

app.register_blueprint(home_page)
app.register_blueprint(download_page)
app.register_blueprint(upload_page, url_prefix="/upload")
app.register_blueprint(favicon_page)

import app.routes as routes
import app.models as models

def serve():
    return app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=1212, debug=True)

And my file tree:
app
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── app.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── routes.py

Am I doing anything wrong here? From what I researched, you cannot use relative imports from the file you are running? Is this correct? I would appreciate any help.

How do you run __main__.py?

when my current dir is the app dir on the first level, i run python app

python -m app

If you run your app module like python app, app/ will be added to sys.path and become your import base.
So, you have to remove app from the imports.
Also your code has to be moved out of __init__.py. In general only module initialization code should go there. In your case you could import __init__, but that's not best practice.

obviously, you seem like a much more experienced programmer than me, but I have had success with putting code in init.py (ik it is not best practice, but it is only when I need to quickly slam something together for one time use) and importing it like from <module_name> import <methodORvariable>

Let's start with the error first
File "/Users/joey/projects/app/app/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import serve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Your file __main__.py is unable to find a module/package named app that you're importing from. When calling for a package like this the app should be in the same directory as the file.
Root_app
├── run.py          // External caller on the package
└── app                  // app that is imported
    ├── __init__.py
    

When you use from app import serve, Python searches for app in sys.path first, and if found, it imports serve from it.
Instead use from . import serve in __main__.py so that it knows to directly search within the same package.

fyi, that was my minimum reproducible example, not the actual code. What really confused me was that I had other python files in the second-level app directory that were able to import from init.py

@s4D_t0y ok mb , I understood your problem after you said that , let me just edit my answer
